# How to replace the value of symbol in x86 assembly using gnu asembler macro? Compose register names like xmm0 from xmm(i)

Tags: assembly, x86, macros, x86-64, gnu-assembler

```
.macro macro_name
  .set i, 0
  .rept 8
    movss  (i * 4)(%rsi), %xmm(i)
    set i , i + 1
  .endr
.endm
```

I wrote this macro to load 8 single precession floating point numbers into `xmm` registers to build the argument for a function.
The expanded  macro should look like this.

```
movss (%rsi), %xmm0
movss 0x4(%rsi), %xmm1
...
movss 0x1c(%rsi), %xmm7
```

The line defined in the macro : `movss  (i * 4)(%rsi), %xmm(i)` : The first expansion `(i * 4)` works as expected but, the second expansion `(i)` doesn't work. It just concatenates like `%xmm(i)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using `.altmacro` and a helper like so:

```
.altmacro
.macro help addr reg
movss \addr(%rsi), %xmm\reg
.endm
.macro macro_name
  .set i, 0
  .rept 8
    help %(i * 4), %(i)
    .set i , i + 1
  .endr
.endm
```